# VBA Code replacing values in column D if cell in column c

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and i tried to create i sub that will update (with vlookup and then copy paste) the comments with new comments from another sheet depending on the case status ("Open"). Basically i tried to put together a code that inserts new rows at the end of the table with a vlookup macro.
The main problem is that i do not know how to instruct excel to identify in which cell he should do the lookup and then copy and paste. As in the example below "M528" will not do it as i want to keep the records that are closed as well. I receive daily only the open cases so therefore i don`t want the code to do any vlookups in those cells where the status is "Closed"

```
Sub ChangesUpdates()


lastRow = Worksheets("CurrentDash").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For r = 2 To lastRow
    If Worksheets("CurrentDash").Range("AS" & r).Value = "Open" Then
        Range("M528").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=VLOOKUP([@[Parent Case Number]],NewData!C[-12]:C,13,0)"
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
       
End Sub
```

Comment: What was the significance of cell `M528` here - was it (for example) the first blank row in column `M`?

Comment: It was the cell that i have selected when i started to record the macro. Row number 528 is one of the many that has a status open (column AS). That is today. But tomorrow this row might be closed so i don`t want a vlookup to be performed.

Comment: Change your code to not use `selection`. Instead of `selection`, use a direct cell reference like you did in your if statement.

Comment: OK so I take it the comment goes into the `M` column of the row under consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing things too much, you can do most of what you want with

```
Sub ChangesUpdates()

lastRow = Worksheets("CurrentDash").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For rw = 2 To lastRow
    If Worksheets("CurrentDash").Range("AS" & rw).Value = "Open" Then
        With Worksheets("CurrentDash").Range("M" & rw)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP([@[Parent Case Number]],NewData!C[-12]:C,13,0)"
            .Value = .Value ' effectively a paste-values
        End With
    End If
Next rw
       
End Sub
```

There's no cell selection/activation here so the screen won't move to the updates, but it should cycle through the same set as your routine.

There's some remaining question in my mind about how stable the lookup area is, which you should think about.

Comment: Thank you very much Joffan. You saved my day. It runs perfect.

Comment: If you feel the Joffan's answer was the correct answer to your question, please click "accept" so that other users with the same problem will more easily be able to find it.